# iOS - UIGestureRecognizer In UITableViewCell Similar To Snapchat

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer, uitableview

I'm trying to implement functionality in my practice app very similar to that of Snapchat, where you drag a `UITableViewCell` to the right or left, and as you're dragging, an image behind the view is slowly appearing until it reaches a certain point, and after it does, it starts a segue or `PageViewController` type segue to another view controller that you can use to chat with your friend.

At first, I tried using the screen edge pan gesture recognizer, but that only works if you start swiping from the edge of the screen. I need to be able to swipe from anywhere within the `UITableViewCell`.

A demonstration of my needed functionality is in Snapchat, where you see it more clearly when you slowly swipe right on one of your friend's table cell's and it slowly shows the image of a messaging icon and eventually leads to another view where you can chat.

So would a pan gesture recognizer be enough for this? If so, what would be the best method to follow to get this done? I've seen tutorials on pan gesture recognizers but I don't see how it could eventually lead to another view controller after swiping a certain distance. I think I could get away with putting the messaging icon behind the displayed table cell content that could appear while swiping right, but how could I implement such smooth functionality?

Learning this would really increase my experience in smooth user experience. Any advice or methods would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: Please leave answers in Objective C, please. I don't know Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom TableViewCell for this. Code below should do what you're asking. Just need to add the delegate to your `ViewController`

```
protocol TableViewCellDelegate {
    func something()
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var startSegue = false
    var label: UILabel                      // Or UIView, whatever you want to show
    var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?    // Delegate to your ViewController to perform the segue

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

        // Utility method for creating the label / view
        func createLabel() -> UILabel {
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.nullRect)

            // Add label customization here

            return label
        }

        // Create "check" & "cross" labels for context cues
        label = createLabel()        // Create the label
        label.text = "\u{2713}"      // Add check symbol as text

        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        addSubview(label)

        // Add a pan recognizer
        var recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
        recognizer.delegate = self
        addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    }

    let cueMargin: CGFloat = 10.0, cueWidth: CGFloat = 50.0

    override func layoutSubviews() {

        // The label starts out of view
        label.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.size.width + cueMargin, y: 0, width: cueWidth, height: bounds.size.height)
    }

    func handleSwipe(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self)

        if recognizer.state == .Changed {
            center = CGPointMake(center.x + translation.x, center.y)
            startSegue = frame.origin.x < -frame.size.width / 2.0                       // If swiped over 50%, return true
            label.textColor = startSegue ? UIColor.redColor() : UIColor.whiteColor()    // If swiped over 50%, become red
            recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self)
        }
        if recognizer.state == .Ended {
            let originalFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)
            if delegate != nil {
                startSegue ? delegate!.something() : UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2) { self.frame = originalFrame }
            }
        }
    }

    // Need this to handle the conflict between vertical swipes of tableviewgesture and pangesture
    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if let panGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
            let velocity = panGestureRecognizer.velocityInView(superview!)
            if fabs(velocity.x) >= fabs(velocity.y) { return true }
            return false
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

I got this from this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77974/making-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-like-clear-in-swift-part-1#comments)

EDIT:
In your ViewController you'll have to 'register' this TableViewCell by using:

```
yourTableName.registerClass(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
```

And your `TableViewDataSource` for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would look like:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell

        cell.delegate = self

        // Add stuff for your other labels like:
        // "cell.name = item.name" etc        

       return cell
    }
```

If you want to pass data back to the `ViewController`, just use the delegate.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know Swift. Is there a way I could get this in Objective-C? If not, I'll try to read this code and try it out by converting it to Objective C. I'll get back to you. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, if you want it to appear smoothly you can use the alpha value for the UIView (or label) and make it go from 0 -> 1 based on the swipe. Sorry, I don't know much about Objective-C. All I know is, it uses brackets `[]` for methods instead of dot notations in Swift.

Comment: I got the pan gesture working a little bit...but this isn't a success yet. Is there a way to make a Swift file, put this code in there, and have it coexist with the rest of my Objective-C files?

Comment: I marked this question correct because it does, indeed, give me what I want. But I can't make it compatible with my objective C code. Thank you very much though, and sorry for taking so long to mark this correct.

Comment: np, whats the problem with mixing with your obj-c code though? You can also use auto layout to do this, maybe that would be easier?